# SQL Server 2008 - Sum of Sums

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have managed to write the following query which returns results I need to see the Occupancy and Capacity for the floors in a building.

```
select 
fma0.bldgcode, 
fma0.floorcode, 
sum(fma0.occ) as Occupancy, 
sum(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
    FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%' THEN FMA0.CAPACITY 
    ELSE 0 END) as Capacity
from fma0 
where fma0.bldgcode = 'tst01' 
group by fma0.bldgcode, fma0.floorcode 
order by fma0.bldgcode, fma0.floorcode
```

But what do I need to add to this in order to get another column for the sum of "Occupancy / Capacity".

Thks

FTD

Comment: If you put `fma0.acc` instead of 0 in the `else` clause for calculating `Capacity`, will you get what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
bldgcode,
floorcode,
Occupancy,
Capacity ,
Occupancy+Capacity AS allsum
FROM(
select 
fma0.bldgcode, 
fma0.floorcode, 
sum(fma0.occ) as Occupancy, 
sum(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
    FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%' THEN FMA0.CAPACITY 
    ELSE 0 END) as Capacity
from fma0 
where fma0.bldgcode = 'tst01' 
group by fma0.bldgcode, fma0.floorcode 

)tmp
order by bldgcode, floorcode
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply timus, however I now get a SQL error: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified"

Comment: Sorted it, moved the ORDER BY to after the tmp line and named the order fields as per the original select.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a CTE as follows (note the other answers thus far are giving you the SUM(SUM(occupance) + SUM(capacity)):

```
WITH CTE_SUMS ([bldgcode], [floorcode], [Occupancy], [Capacity])
AS  (
    SELECT 
        fma0.bldgcode AS [bldgcode], 
        fma0.floorcode AS [floorcode], 
        sum(fma0.occ) AS [Occupancy], 
        sum(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
            FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%' THEN FMA0.CAPACITY 
            ELSE 0 END) AS [Capacity]
    FROM fma0 
    WHERE fma0.bldgcode = 'tst01' 
    GROUP BY fma0.bldgcode, fma0.floorcode
    )
SELECT [bldgcode], [floorcode], [Occupancy], [Capacity], ([Occupancy] / [Capacity]) AS [Sum]
FROM CTE_SUMS
```

This will basically give you SUM(occupancy)/SUM(capacity) with the grouping already accounted for.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
bldgcode,
floorcode,
Occupancy,
Capacity ,
Occupancy+Capacity AS allsum
FROM(
select 
fma0.bldgcode, 
fma0.floorcode, 
sum(fma0.occ) as Occupancy, 
sum(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%' THEN FMA0.CAPACITY 
ELSE 0 END) as Capacity
from fma0 
where fma0.bldgcode = 'tst01' 
group by fma0.bldgcode, fma0.floorcode 
)tmp
order by bldgcode, floorcode
```

Comment: -1 because you copied answer .. this is not a way you participate on stackoverflow.. if you got answer keep practice on upvote and accepting answers

Comment: I copied the original answer from Timus but moved the order by line to the correct place as the original was giving an error as stated in the comments. Timus has since edited his answer to be the same! Again as stated in the comments....please read before critising